# ASP.NET – Making Asynchronous calls to the Server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

Good morning.

We are building an ASP.NET website and in that we have one big page having 4 GridViews.  Each grids have sorting feature enabled.  We need to make an asynchronous call to the server for each grid (whenever a user clicks on a column of a grid view to sort) so that it renders fast (instead of full page getting refreshed each time).

Is there a best tutorial or web reference explaining making these asynchronous calls?

Thanks and Regards..

Shruthi Keerthi

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this would be to wrap each grid in an UpdatePanel and let ASP.NET ajax handle the details.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asp.net/ajax

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising

http://www.ajaxmatters.com/articles/asp/ajax_grid_icallbackeventhandler_p1.aspx

You could also look into ASP.NET Ajax and the UpdatePanel -- only recommended for simple, low usage pages.